# redirect curl output to stdout and log files

Tags: bash, curl

How do i get curl output on both stdout and log files?

This will redirect to log files.

```
curl -o $OUTPUTFILE 2>>$LOGFILES $url
```

And this will show output on stdout.

```
curl -o $OUTPUTFILE $url
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use `tee`:

```
curl -o $OUTPUTFILE $URL 2>&1 | tee $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Bingo that solves it. adding -a option to tee function solves the entire problem of logging. Thanks :)

Comment: if i do that i wont be able to get the return value from curl operation. I will be getting only the return value for the tee operation. You've any suggestion ?

Comment: Nice! didn't even know about `$PIPESTATUS`! Was looking into it here myself.

Comment: i was surprised to see it myself too! read about it [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/92163-command-does-not-return-exit-status-due-tee.html)

Comment: @Antarus in bash, use this to get curl's return code: ${PIPESTATUS[0]}